# How to get the related Opp ID from the Quote object to the related task created from the Quote

Tags: process-builder

I have a field called " Opportunity Name" ( field name " opportunity")in the quote object, which is a look up to the opp object.

I want that, when i create a Task from this quote, the opp name ( which is actually a auto -number set )

[image]

In the task field, the opp number should get reflected. I have created a look up field in the Task object " opportunity" ( also a text datatype field " Opportunity Number" , whichever would convenient to bring the value)
I tried the process builder and work flow with various options but the issue is in teh Task object, the value is not geting reflected. can anyone suggest a way ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for me your question is not clear. Why you do'nt use formula field if you have already the lookup?

Comment: Hi, Akram , i tried to create a formula field as well in the task object( Activity object), with the formula detail as " quote__r.Opportunity.Name" . but dont know why its not working in teh Task object. My main motto is to bring the quote activties to reflect in the opp level, but till the opp no. will not reflect in the Task details page, its not going to show in the related opp. If you can suggest a way. thnx